# How to create interstitial ads using delphi 11.0

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal, delphi-11-alexandria

How can I create interstitial ads using Delphi 11.0? The following code does not work in Delphi 11.0, but it was working in older version.

```pascal
TMyAdViewListener = class(TJavaLocal, JIAdListener)
private
  FAD: JInterstitialAd;
public
  constructor Create(AAD: JInterstitialAd);
  procedure onAdClosed; cdecl;
  procedure onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Integer); cdecl;
  procedure onAdLeftApplication; cdecl;
  procedure onAdOpened; cdecl;
  procedure onAdLoaded; cdecl;
end;

var
  LAdViewListener: TMyAdViewListener;
  FInterStitial: JInterstitialAd;

FInterstitial := TJInterstitialAd.JavaClass.init(MainActivity);
FInterstitial.setAdUnitId(StringToJString('xx-ad-id-xx'));

LADRequestBuilder := TJAdRequest_Builder.Create;
LadRequest := LADRequestBuilder.build();
LAdViewListener := TMyAdViewListener.Create(FInterStitial);
CallInUIThread(
  procedure
  begin
    try
      FInterStitial.setAdListener(TJAdListenerAdapter.JavaClass.init(LAdViewListener));
      FInterStitial.loadAd(LadRequest);
    except
    end;
  end
);
```

Please help to resolve the issue. I tried with the sample code, but it does not work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" exactly.  Are you getting any errors? Which version of Android are you running this code on? The code you have shown doesn't look anything like the code in the Android documentation: [Interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.